# Configuring site permissions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, custom, list-form

Perhaps I don't know how to search for this but I cant manage to find anything in the forums here that address this specifically.  If I am in error concerning that PLEASE point me in the right direction, otherwise this is my issue:

I have created a form based on a list I have created for capturing "engagements" (new task requests for a team within my department).  The goal of this form is to help us make record of (and track) tasks from other departments we get in hallway conversations, emails or IM clients.  A way for us to say "yeah sure we can help you with that...but please go here and file a request so I have something to log my time against."  We call that request an "Engagement" so my list is an "Engagement Request" list and it lives on our SharePoint 2010 Team site.  *Yes I am aware there are a plethora of ticketing systems out there that might be able to better facilitate this but that isn't an option for us and I am the poor sod tasked with making it happen  using SharePoint.

What I am trying to do is set the permissions for the NewForm.aspx associated with this list so that anyone with a AD account can access it to create a new item (an "engagement request") but lock down access to the rest of the site..including the list (because one person who is engaging us for a password rest has no business seeing the record/status of our other engagements.  At this point I have figured out how to route the users (who have previously requested and been granted access to the site) from the Engagement form BACK to the the main menu so they don't automatically see the list.  Basically I added an image top the Top level team site that says "Engagement", linked it directly to the NewForm.aspx URL and appended it with the "?source=https//" bit at the end which will re-direct the user back to the Toplevel site on save/submit rather than the Allitems display of the list they just added a new item (Engagement) to.

Ok now that I have explained all that...and I apologize for the overly verbose nature of this post but what I need to do is set it so that anyone with a valid AD account can access the top level site of the teamsite...and Add a new item to the engagement list... but that is all, nothing else.  I cant allow them to go into the other lists and libraries on the teamsite.  My research indicates that I can set unique permissions on things all the way down to files but I cant seem to wrap my mind around how to grant automatic access to the toplevel site (and the NewForm.aspx) but NOT everything else.

I have been assigned as one of the owners of said site so I should have the required permissions to do this. Im just not sure HOW to do this.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

~Confused SharePoint Teamsite owner

Answer (score 0):

What i understand you want all user can access one list only and all other List/library/subsite should not be accessible.

What i think.

- Give Read access on the top level site to Nt auth
- On Engagement List gave Nt AUTH more than read so that they can add an item.
- Now on all other list and library, you have to stop inheritance
- remove everybody from the permission
- only add the person which you want to allow use that list/library or subsite.